# Azure AKS get-credentials does not work when called inside a docker container

Tags: azure-aks

I am running *Jenkins* as a dockerised master and have included Azure CLI in the image.
When the following is called
`az aks get-credentials --resource-group amdDevResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster`
returns

> ForbiddenError: The client 'ff761a5f-3caf-4534-a007-5dde398d8dc0' with object id 'ff761a5f-3caf-4534-a007-5dde398d8dc0' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action' over scope '/subscriptions/caafd4f0-659a-4da7-b613-d7ef3d5225a7/resourceGroups/amdDevResourceGroup/providers  /Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myAKSCluster' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

The same command works in the Azure shell.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You probably have a service principal of some kind configured for the container (used in az login). Check that the service principal has "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User" role on the cluster.

Comment: When logged in Azure shell, you're connected with your azure identity and service principal which belongs to a role which has that 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action' or any of the List user credential types of permissions.
You'll need to create a service principal for Jenkins and assign it the role "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User".